# Error on dotnet watch run in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am getting following Error on running dotnet watch run.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. 
Error on line number '0': ''. -
--> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from 
JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0
at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings 
settings)   at 

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.Parse(Stream input)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at WebApplicationBasic.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in \Microservices\TestProject\Startup.cs:line 25
```

I confirmed there is nothing wrong json file. Adding my project files if that helps. This may be irrelevant but I am not sure where to look.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=localhost; database=TestProject; Integrated Security=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs :

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
     Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     // Add framework services.
     services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
     services.AddMvc();
     // services.AddMvcCore()
     // .AddApiExplorer();

     return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

Any suggestion where to start looking?

Comment: Check the encoding of your file doesn't cause issues. You should be able to save them with a specific encoding. The fact its failing on line 0 implies encoding, since it probably found the file, but it can't parse even the first char.

Comment: I'm sure it's a typo, but just to confirm: are you aware that you are loading "appsettings.json" but your file is called "AppSetting.json" ?

Comment: you added `appsettings.json`, but do you have also `appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json`? Maybe the problem in that file.

Comment: I have two files - appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json. The Development one is empty

Comment: I want to add that before this I was getting another error which I resolved by creating DataContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<TestDbContext>.

Comment: I suspect that either the file is empty, or it begins with a UTF-8 BOM. For reasons of insanity, JSON files are explicitly forbidden from using a BOM at the start, even though that codepoint can appear anywhere else in the file.

Comment: Thank You Ben. It was because of empty file. This is weird since is expecting something in that environment file (appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json) but the error was not at all helpful.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO Please put your suggestion as solution so I can mark it complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that either the file is empty, or it begins with a UTF-8 BOM.

The clue is here:

```
Error on line number '0': ''. -
```

The thing it is complaining about is invisible : `''`

So possibly it is either nothing was found where something is expected, or it is an invisible character of some sort, which would include `'\uFEFF'`, the BOM.

For reasons of insanity, JSON files are explicitly forbidden from using a BOM at the start, even though that codepoint can appear anywhere else in the file.